# What is the equivalent of Matlab's eigenvalues in an Armadillo

Tags: c++, matlab, armadillo

I want to convert a Matlab script to C++, and I used the Armadillo library. I have a dense matrix, which I use `eigs()` in Matlab to limit the largest magnitude eigenvalues say 3.

```
[V,E] = eigs(B,3,'LA');
```

---

However, I found the `eigs_sym` only support sparse matrix;

Is there any way to handle such job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Google and go to [armadillo docs](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) you can clearly see that `eigs_sym` gives you eigenvalues of a sparse matrix (hence the S in eig**S**_sym), and that `eig_sym` will give them for a dense matrix.

Comment: You are right, but eig_sym can not limit the number of eigenvalues, I need to write some code to handle this task. I tried to convert the dense matrix to sparse matrix, after that, I use eigs_sym successfully.

Comment: @cityCoder As fr as I know numerically you need to calculate all the eigenvalues in one go, so it takes the same amount of time to do the calculation, but then you throw numbers away. If your matrix is not intrinsically sparse, do not declare it as sparse. It ill consume x3 memory and the computation time will highly increase. If your matrix was sparse already, then you the sparse solver was your option from the beggining.

Comment: Briguri Oh, thanks for your information, then I will use eig_sym as your suggestion